# oAuth 2 authorization header syntax

Tags: oauth-2.0

The oAuth 2 specification requires that authorization headers be structured as follows

`authorization: Bearer token_code`

What's the point of adding `Bearer` ? and I think that would mean than when I access it on the server side, I need to extract `token_code` from the string ?

Can I choose to implement this as follows

`authorization: token_code` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but it is specified that way to distinguish it from other schemes of authentication. For example, basic auth will result on something like:

`Authorization: Basic adsada..dasdsd`

If you control all endpoints (and don't worry too much about interoperability), you can use whatever you want. Even a different header. I would strongly encourage you to follow the standard though, so your code can be understood by anyone coming after you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but just to be clear, if I'm using that scheme, when a request comes in, I'd be doing something like this `token = headers['authorization'].split(' ')` right ?

Comment: Yes. Something like that. Or (if you ever support multiple schemes, then something like "startsWith('Basic')", etc. Notice it is "Authorization" with capital "A".  Good luck!